# updating welogic.xml

Tags: weblogic

my weblogic.xml looks like this

```
<security-role-assignment>
<role-name>employee</role-name>
<principal-name>scott</principal-name>
<principal-name>john</principal-name>
<principal-name>peter</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

But when i add new employee(programmatically) lets us say 'mark' i want weblogic.xml
to be updated for 'mark' also. Actually i can see new employee in admin portal.
But weblogic.xml will not be updated.
How to this programmatically. Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The principal-name elements can be set to groups or defined roles inside WebLogic Server, depending on the version of WebLogic Server you're using.

The shortest answer to your question is that using a more flexible security model (basing the employee role ideally on a group inside WebLogic Server) will remove this problem completely, and make your life a lot easier.

It's how scalable security is intended to work with WebLogic Server.